# Problem trying to merge inputs and outputs of 2 models

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to merge 2 models trained with different datasets and number of classes to get a final model with a unique input and a unique output.

The final result should be something like that:

[diagram of the final model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwYMJ.png)

Actually my code is like that:

```
[...]
stuffs with imports, tensorboard and imageDataGenerator
[...]    

model_simple = load_model("model_simple.h5")
model_simple.name = 'model_simple'
for layer in model_simple.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
    layer.name = layer.name + str("_simple")

model_complexe = load_model("model_complexe.h5")
model_complexe.name = 'model_complexe'
for layer in model_complexe.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
    layer.name = layer.name + str("_complexe")


model_simple.layers.pop(0)
model_complexe.layers.pop(0)

input_common = Input(shape=(299, 299, 3), name="input_common")

model_simple_output = model_simple(input_common)
model_complexe_output = model_complexe(input_common)


x = concatenate([model_simple_output, model_complexe_output])
x = Dense((2 * NB_CLASSES), activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense((2 * NB_CLASSES)*2, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense((2 * NB_CLASSES)*2, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(NB_CLASSES, activation='relu')(x)
output = Dense(NB_CLASSES, activation='sigmoid')(x)


model = Model(inputs=input_common, outputs=output)

model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.0001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-8, amsgrad=True), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])



model.fit_generator(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=NB_FIC_TRAIN // BATCH_SIZE,
        epochs=1,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        validation_steps=NB_FIC_VAL // BATCH_SIZE,
        callbacks = [tensorboard]
        )

model.save("modele_final.h5")
```

When i launch it, it don't crash and it's training but when i look closer it seems to be a big mess (and it throws errors when i'm trying to convert it to .pb saying that the model has 0 tensor inputs).

The final file have almost the same size as the model_simple.h5 file and when i look at the file with netron, the differents parts (2 models and Dense layers) don't seems to be connected:

[The input don't seems to be connected to anything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gKkP.png)

(the "simple" model's layers are to the left and the "complexe" model's layers are to the right)

And the concatenation layer have models as inputs instead of the models outputs:

[Weird inputs for the concatenation layer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTbCe.jpg)

And it's the same if i use ".output" like that :

```
[...]

model_simple_output = model_simple(input_common)
model_complexe_output = model_complexe(input_common)

new_model_simple = Model(input_common, model_simple_output)
new_model_complexe = Model(input_common, model_complexe_output)

x = concatenate([new_model_simple.output, new_model_complexe.output])

[...]
```

I think I'm doing something wrong but i don't get to know what :/

Comment: Did you print your `model.summary()`?
Just try the experiment with 3 very simple models and check the `summary()`.

Comment: Also maybe you should use the `Concatenate([first, second])` layer. Not sure if that makes a difference. Your final model is definitely not connected right now.

Comment: for the model.summary(), here is the result: https://i.gyazo.com/38b06fa4c449779d3683f145e6d412b8.png


I tried with keras.layers.Concatenate like that : `x = Concatenate()([model_simple_output, model_complexe_output])`

but the result is the same :/

Comment: Are the shapes exactly how you expected them?

Comment: Yeah it looks right to me, just the inputs of concatenate should be the output of the 2 models but this should give it : `model_simple_output = model_simple(input_common)` no ?

Comment: I don't understand what is the actual problem or question, you say it trains but then you get errors (which?), and then you use some tool to visualize but then see nonsense results (maybe the tool is broken?). Your model summary looks correct, so I don't see a problem at all.

Comment: Ah maybe I misinterpreted the problem yeah, when I try to convert the final model it also says that the input file specified only holds the weights but I thought it was caused by a malformed structure because I am using `model.save("")` and not `model.save_weights("")`. Here is the complete error : https://i.gyazo.com/c51c82f839607bc2653c85fec99c3588.jpg

Comment: @EnzoDutra So, as you shown the error, your question is how to convert .h5 file to .pb file or some other question? Because `model.summary()` looks okay. There is no problem with your model, it is perfectly concated.

Comment: I don't know because I never had any problem to convert .h5 file to .pb file, I just converted another model to be sure and it works perfectly but there seems to be a problem with the model I'm building here. Maybe it save the structure of the Dense layers I add but not the structure of the 2 models ? I also have a weird graph structure on tensorboard where every parts don't seems linked. (here is the file I'm getting if you want to check it https://desfichesdescartes.fr/projet/modele_total_3.h5)

Comment: @EnzoDutra, I think you have some custom stuff inside your model which is creating the issue may be some custom layer. Is this correct or not?

Comment: I don't think so, I tried with 2 official Inception V3 model that i've got like that https://i.gyazo.com/5adf6927c143461fed17a0c5367f078b.png and the problems are exactly the same. Here is the full version of the code above if you want to try  https://pastebin.com/uqChMnVc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to create your use case using VGG16 and VGG19 as follows:

```
from keras.layers import *
from keras.models import *
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from keras.applications.vgg19 import VGG19

model_1 = VGG16(include_top=True, weights='imagenet')
model_2 = VGG19(include_top=True, weights='imagenet')
```

And then I had used part of your script to concat the model.

```
NB_CLASSES = 73

input_common = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3), name="input_common")

model_simple_output = model_1(input_common)
model_complexe_output = model_2(input_common)

x = concatenate([model_simple_output, model_complexe_output])
x = Dense((2 * NB_CLASSES), activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense((2 * NB_CLASSES)*2, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense((2 * NB_CLASSES)*2, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(NB_CLASSES, activation='relu')(x)
output = Dense(NB_CLASSES, activation='sigmoid')(x)

model = Model(inputs=input_common, outputs=output)
```

To save the model. It should also work if you only use `model.save`. But you can also try to save your model as json using [`model.to_json()`](https://keras.io/models/about-keras-models/) which will save the model as string. And it will not save your weights and if you want to save weights separately use `model.save_weights`.

```
model.summary()
model.save('model.h5')

model_json = model.to_json()
with open("model.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)
```

I probably used the same file to convert `.h5` file to `.pb` that you have used.

```
git clone https://github.com/amir-abdi/keras_to_tensorflow.git

python keras_to_tensorflow/keras_to_tensorflow.py --input_model=model.h5 \
                                                  --input_model_json=model.json \
                                                  --output_model=model.pb
```

`keras_to_tensorflow.py` also works without `--input_model_json=model.json` because `model.h5` contains both model and weights. But for your case, I would prefer to use with `--input_model_json`. I think it should work for you.

Comment: That's strange it seems to work with VGG16 and VGG19 but not with InceptionV3 and InceptionResNetV2, it makes the conversion scripts freeze and the .h5 file size seems really small. It looks like there's a problem when the script that build the model save it. 
Do you think it could be a bug ? 
Or maybe it's because VGG are sequential graphs and not the inceptions ones and they can't be manipulated the same way ?

Comment: Also I don't know why but when I use the code you gave but with 2 VGG16 instead of VGG16 and VGG19, I have this error when using the conversion script https://i.gyazo.com/68970e4bec3b6f52584f15142027f0cb.png